# Devise and routes for omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, linkedin-api, omniauth

I am using Devise for authentication users, this is what is in the **routes.rb** file:

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret',
                                    :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unlock', :registration => 'register',
                                    :sign_up => 'signup' }
```

And I added a part for omniauth (for LinkedIn):

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret',
                                    :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unlock', :registration => 'register',
                                    :sign_up => 'signup' }, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

In the view:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
  <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => :delete %>
  <% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or
  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Linkedin",user_omniauth_authorize_path(:linkedin) %>
<% end %>
```

And the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"omniauth_callbacks", :action=>"passthru", :provider=>:linkedin, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:provider]
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Comment: What's the exact name of the omniauth gem you are using?

Comment: `gem 'omniauth'` and `gem 'omniauth-linkedin'`

Comment: Did you update the model and devise config with twitter omniauth? This article is pretty good http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

Answer (score 2):

Verify consistent spelling of your provider in all places referenced.
The data below is an example of :facebook as the provider.

Model file with devise omniauthable call

```
# app/models/User.rb
  devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
```

Devise config for provider

```
# app/config/initializers/devise.rb
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email, name'
```

^-- Also, Register with the provider to acquire your developer APP_ID & APP_SECRET

Callbacks Controller:

```
# app/controllers/callbacks_controller.rb
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    ... more code here, excess omitted ...
  end
```

URI path within a view file

```
# apps/views/shared/_footer.html.erb
  user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
```

In this case, I only use the provider specific gem:

```
# app_name/Gemfile
  gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

I'm not using the #omniauth gem as devise is omniauthable (we use devise.rb instead of omniauth.rb inside initialize as middleware configuration). Ref : Paragraph below **Before you Start** on *Devise Overview wiki* : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview

Still no love? Then I'd check the omniauth-**provider** gem for any specifics in use. Facebook changed their OAuth API around July - Aug 2015, so one needs this last part in the config (shown above, Devise Config, devise.rb) to get the user's email address and name :

```
  info_fields: 'email, name'
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks that explains how to format code blocks correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @MathiasMüller , I edited the answer. Let me know what I missed in the formatting if it's still off. Thanks.

Comment: Now the formatting is perfect, thanks for improving it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
  <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => :delete %>
  <% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or
  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Linkedin",user_omniauth_authorize_path(provider: :linkedin) %>
<% end %>
```

omniauth path takes `provider` option.

Comment: Thanks Paritosh for your answer. Though, I still face this issue: `No route matches {:controller=>"omniauth_callbacks", :action=>"passthru", :provider=>"linkedin"} missing required keys: [:provider]`

Comment: please post the output of `rake routes | grep omniauth`